# Report using Sql and Gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql

Hi Guys i need to generate following report format..but not getting any logic in sql and gridviwe.Report show previous four month data including current month.
please suggest ..
Please see below report format

[Report Format](http://www4.picturepush.com/photo/a/11706807/640/11706807.jpg)

Comment: try to create data table with some manipulation in code. And then bind your grid from your datatable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pivot](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/07/sql-server-pivot-and-unpivot-table-examples/) and [cube](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/09/27/aggregation-with-cube.aspx) to solve your problem.

An example is below
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2007/09/27/aggregation-with-cube.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201320/Dynamic-Pivoting-with-Cubes-and-eventhandlers-in-S